# Suppose that $0 \le f(n) \le 1$, why $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - f(n))^n = 0 \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)n = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, limits

Suppose that $0 \le f(n) \le 1$ and consider two eqauation:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - f(n))^n = 0 \tag{A} $$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)n = \infty \tag{B} $$

It seems that A and B are equivalent. But how we can show it formally?
Maybe you know a reference for this result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean $0 \leqslant f(n) \leqslant 1$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. I mean $0 \le f(n) \le n$.

Comment: In that case they're certainly not equivalent. Consider $f(n) = n$, evidently $f(n)n\to\infty$, but $(1-f(n))^n \not\to 0$.

Comment: Can't we take $f(x) = x$? Then $0 \leq f(n) \leq n$ for all natural numbers $n$, and the limit in (B) is infinite limit, but the limit in (A) is not zero?

Comment: Oups, double sorry. Actually, @DanielFischer is right. Because $f(n)$ is not just a function, but it is "a probability of smth".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $1-x\leqslant\mathrm e^{-x}$ for every $x$, hence $(1-x)^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{-nx}$ for every $x\leqslant1$, in particular $(1-f(n))^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{-nf(n)}$. Thus, $nf(n)\to\infty$ implies $(1-f(n))^n\to0$.

In the other direction, if $nf(n)$ does not converge to infinity, there exists infinitely many $n_k$ and some finite $C$ such that $n_kf(n_k)\leqslant C$, hence $(1-f(n_k))^{n_k}\geqslant(1-C/n_k)^{n_k}$ for every $k$ large enough. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}(1-C/x)^x=\mathrm e^{-C}$ and $n_k\to\infty$, this yields $(1-f(n_k))^{n_k}\geqslant\mathrm e^{-C}/2\gt0$ for every $k$ large enough, in particular $(1-f(n))^n$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: wow! I always forget that it is possible to prove by contradiction.  If someone wants to know the possible application of the proven equivalence, then...

Comment: then... **a random graph $G(n,p)$ have diameter 2 almost surely if and only if $np^2 \to \infty$**.

Take two vertices from $G(n,p)$, say $u$ and $v$. 
With probability $1-p$ the distance between $u$ and $v$ is greater than 1.
With probability $(1-p)(1-p^2)^{n-2}$ the distance between $u$ and $v$ is greater than 2.
(Take a vertex $c \notin \{u,v\}$. $1-p^2$ is the probability that $c$ is not connected. We have $n-2$ candidates for vertex $c$).
So, we have: 
$ (1-p)(1-p^2)^{n-2} \to 0 \iff p^2n \to \infty $